# Laravel chained dropdown selection using jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm using laravel 5.6 and I've made dropdown selection but it didn't work. I choosed a province in dropdown menu provinces but the menu city not shown up the data of cities. 
This is my controller :

```
public function province()
      {
        $prov = Province::orderBy("provinsi.id","ASC")
                        ->pluck("name","id");
        return view('auth.register',compact('prov')); 
      }

public function cities($id)
      {
        $city = City::where("id_provinsi","=",$id)
                      ->pluck("city_name","id");
        return json_encode($city);
      }
```

This is my route:

```
Route:: get('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@province');
Route:: get('/register/cities/{id}', 'Auth\RegisterController@cities');
```

This is my view:

```
<div class="form-group row">

 <label for="prov" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Provinsi') }}</label>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <select name="prov" class="form-control">
        <option value="">=== Choose Province ===</option>
          @foreach ($prov as $key=>$value)                               
             <option value="{{$key}}">{{$value}}</option>                                    
          @endforeach
      </select>
       </div>
        </div>
 <div class="form-group row">
   <label for="city" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('City') }}</label>
  <div class="col-md-6">
   <select name="cities" class="form-control"> </select>
    </div>
     </div>
```

This is my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function()
  {
      $('select[name="prov"]').on('change', function() {
          var provID = $(this).val();
          if(provID) {
              $.ajax({
                  url: '/register/cities/'+provID,
                  type: "GET",
                  dataType: "json",
                  success:function(data) {                      
                      $('select[name="cities"]').empty();
                      $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                          $('select[name="cities"]').append('<option value="'+ key +'">'+ value +'</option>');
                      });
                  }
              });
          }else{
              $('select[name="cities"]').empty();
          }
      });
  });

</script>
```

I got the data json if I open the url /register/cities/(any province id) .

Comment: You can return HTML content from your controller. And just append it in your city dropdown is rendering.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the response returned in

```
public function cities($id) { ... }
```

is in JSON format.

To do this check network log in your browser (in Firefox o Chrome F12 -> Net:XHR -> Response) or add a `colsole.log(data)` in the success callback.

Comment: I check on my firefox, got status 404. hmmm.

Comment: It's not good! But at least we understand where the problem is :)
Change this line: "url: '/register/cities/'+provID".
Give an absolute url and and verify that provID variable is set.

Comment: after I change my url. now the city menu shown [object Object] not the name of the cities.

Answer (score 1):

in your view replace you second `select`

```
 <select name="cities" class="form-control" id='cities'> </select>
```

your first select change this

```
<select name="prov" class="form-control">
  <option value="">=== Choose Province ===</option>
    @foreach ($prov as $key=>$value)                               
        option value="{{$value->id}}">{{$value->name}}</option>                                    
    @endforeach
</select>
```

next changue in your controller

```
public function cities($id)
 {
   $city = City::where("id_provinsi",$id)->get()              
   return response()->json(['cities' => $city], 200);
 }
```

changue this in your `each` inside `ajax`

```
$.each(data.cities, function(key, value) {
 $('#cities').append('<option value="'+ value.id+'">'+ value.name +'</option>');
});
```

changue your `url` ajax for this

```
 url:"{{ url('/register/cities/') }}/"+provID;
```

Comment: it doesnt work. in my console chrome, shown up http://myweb/register/cities/2 404 ()

Comment: error 404 if for no found 
Verify well that you are sending the parameters correctly

Comment: i change my url from my javascript to my absolute url and now it's work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function cities($id)
{
        $city = City::where("id_provinsi","=",$id)
                      ->pluck("city_name","id");

       $html = view('city_list', compact('city'))->render();
        return response()->json([
            'html' => $html             
        ]);

}
```

city_list.blade.php

```
<select name="city" class="form-control">
    <option value="">=== Choose City===</option>
  @foreach ($city as $key=>$value)                               
     <option value="{{$key}}">{{$value}}</option>                                    
  @endforeach
</select>
```